# iOS - Can't get custom view to center in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I'm having awful trouble getting a custom view to display correctly in a UIViewController. I'm new to iOS and am not sure if I am constraining this correctly.

I have a BaseTabBarController which sets up my three tabs and controllers which works fine. It is in my MainFeedViewController where I'm having trouble constraining my custom views. Currently, my custom view either appears off the top left corner of the device, or when setting constraints programatically as below, the view is anchored to the right side of the screen, and when the device rotates, it's as if the view controller keeps its portrait size in landscape mode.

I'm baffled and need some guidance on setting constraints properly to have the view centred.

Also, should I set the size of my custom view in its Xib, or will it conform to the view size I set the container view to in the MainFeedViewController?

```
class MainFeedViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var articlePreview: ArticlePreviewView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
      setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
      view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "standardBackgroundColor")
      articlePreview.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
      articlePreview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
      articlePreview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
      articlePreview.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    }
}
```

```
class ArticlePreviewView: UIView {

  @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
  @IBOutlet weak var articleInfoContainer: UIView!

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    initSubviews()
  }

  override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    initSubviews()
  }

  func initSubviews() {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "ArticlePreviewView", bundle: nil)
    nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)
    addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    setupViewTheme()
  }

  func setupViewTheme() {
    contentView.backgroundColor = .blue
    //articleInfoContainer.backgroundColor = .white
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: dont use X,Y constraints with left,right

Comment: Why not? Also, removing the X,Y constraints did nothing to change the views location

Comment: In your view controller, you show: ` @IBOutlet weak var articlePreview: ArticlePreviewView!` ... which indicates you have added it in Storyboard. Did you set constraints on it in Storyboard, and then you're also setting constraints via code?

Comment: No. I had no constraints on it other than height & width in IB. I set the X & Y constraints via code

Comment: @Dylan - hmm... we need a little more information then. In IB, you set the width & height, and you want it centered? Why not also add Horizontally and Vertically centered constraints?

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix auto layout with auto resizing mask and frame size. Remove the code in ArticlePreviewView that sets the frame and autoResizingMask and use constraints, if you want the view to fill its superview you can use

```
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor),
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor),
            view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor),
            view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor)
            ])
```

Comment: That seems to make the entire viewcontroller dissapear (I think). The background loses its colour and the articlePreview is no longer visible.

Comment: So actually if I set translatemaskintoconstraints in the IB, the background colour is now fully visible in both portrait and landscape mode. So I guess that is a step in the right direction. Although, the articlePreview still has the same problem

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by that please? I'm not understanding what you mean by that

Comment: @matchifang - *"You should not mix auto layout with auto resizing mask and frame size."* ... that's not correct. The "root view" of a xib loads with `.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` set to true. That means it **uses the resizing mask** to tell auto-layout what to do with it. That is entirely appropriate.